# Accessing elements in an NgFor loop

Tags: angular, angular2-template

My template contains a dynamic list:

```
<ol>
  <li #nameitem *ngFor="let name of names; let i = index" class="classA"     
      (click)="handleClick(i)">{{ name }}</li>
</ol>
```

I want to change an item's CSS class when the user clicks on it. I've tried using properties of the `MouseEvent` such as `target` and `currentTarget`, but the `EventTarget` doesn't provide access to the class list. So I tried obtaining the list elements as view children:

```
@ViewChildren("nameitem") private nameItems: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

This isn't working either. In the event handler, the native element is undefined:

```
private handleClick(i: number) {
  console.log(this.nameItems[i].nativeElement.classList.length);
}
```

The error I get is: `Cannot read property "nativeElement" of undefined`. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: if you pass `$event` in handleClick then you can get hold of target from $event and update the class.

Comment: When I first tried that, it failed for some reason. But I just tried that again and it worked. Bizarre. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

A `QueryList`'s elements can't be accessed with array notation unless `toArray` is used. So this code fails:

```
console.log(this.nameItems[i].nativeElement.classList.length);
```

And this code works:

```
console.log(this.nameItems.toArray()[i].nativeElement.classList.length);
```

Crazy. If anyone knows a better way, please let me know.

Comment: that is crazy. I used this in Angular 10 (we need to upgrade...) today (April 13, 2022)